# Adding onclick attribute to a dynamically created option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script where I am appending options to a select item and would add the onclick method to them.

My piece of code is this:

```
$(obj).closest('td').next('td').find('.select').append(new Option("i", "i"));
```

and this is how it looks when I inspect them:

```
<option value="i">i</option>
```

but I want them to be

```
<option onclick="functionname" value="i">i</option>
```

Is there anyway to do it with jQuery? Thanks in advance

Comment: `$(obj).closest('td').next('td').find('.select').on("change",function() { if (this.value==="i") functionName() })`

Answer (score 3):

A much better idea would be to put a click event handler on the `select` itself, then read the `value` which was selected.

This is for two reasons. Firstly inline event attributes, such as `onclick`, are no longer good practice and should be avoided where possible. Secondly, event handlers on `option` elements are unreliable at best and just plain don't work at worst.

The best way to achieve what you need is to add a `change` event handler to the `select` and read the selected value from the chosen option at that point, something like this:

```js
let $foo = $('#foo').on('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});

$('button').on('click', () => {
  let ts = (new Date()).getTime();
  $foo.append(`<option value="${ts}">${ts}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add option</button>
<select id="foo"></select>
```

Comment: I guess there is also a .select method in jquerry , maybe it could also help

Comment: jQuery does have a `select()` method, but it's not relevant to this case at all

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it for an `onclick` attribute since, as already stated, there are faster and better ways to reference it directly from JS. But for future reference or if you need to set other attributes, you can use the built in `setAttribute`. An example would be `yourelement.setAttribute("class","classname")`.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new option, you could create a listener for that select like this:

```
jQuery('select').change(function(){ 
    const value = jQuery(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

```js
jQuery('select').append(new Option('New Option', 'value'));

jQuery('select').change(function(){ 
    const value = jQuery(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```